Anchor solana use instruction instead of .rpc
here is my mint method it works as expected but i am getting this dapp could be malicious do not print unless you are certain this is safe If i want this warning to be immediately resolved, i need to  change dApp to use the signAndSendTransaction method
export default async function mintNFT(metadata: MintNFTResponse, wallet) {
    //
    const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
        preflightCommitment: commitmentLevel,
    });

    const signer = provider.wallet as AnchorWallet;

    if (!provider) {
        throw new Error("No provider found");
    }

    const program = new Program(
        solanaNFTprogramInterface,
        solanaNFTprogramId,
        provider
    ) as Program<SolanaNft>;

    program.addEventListener("MintedEvent", (event, slot) => {
        eventEmitter.emit("minted", event);
    });

    const umi = createUmi(endpoint)
        .use(walletAdapterIdentity(signer))
        .use(mplTokenMetadata());

    const mint = web3.Keypair.generate();

    const associatedTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        mint.publicKey,
        signer.publicKey
    );

    let metadataAccount = findMetadataPda(umi, {
        mint: publicKey(mint.publicKey),
    })[0];

    let masterEditionAccount = findMasterEditionPda(umi, {
        mint: publicKey(mint.publicKey),
    })[0];

    const tx = await program.methods
        .mintNft(metadata.name, metadata.symbol, metadata.uri, mintPrice)
        .accounts({
            metadataAccount,
            mint: mint.publicKey,
            masterEditionAccount,
            associatedTokenAccount,
            signer: signer.publicKey,
            rent: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            recipient: config.recipientPubKey,
            systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            tokenMetadataProgram: MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
        })
        .signers([mint])
        .rpc();

    console.log(
        `mint nft tx: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${tx}?cluster=devnet`
    );
    console.log(
        `minted nft: https://explorer.solana.com/address/${mint.publicKey}?cluster=devnet`
    );

    return tx;

i want to use instruction and signAndSendTransaction method from phanthom
i tried this but it's not working
export default async function mintNFT(metadata: MintNFTResponse, wallet) {
    //

    const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {
        preflightCommitment: commitmentLevel,
    });

    const signer = provider.wallet as AnchorWallet;

    if (!provider) {
        throw new Error("No provider found");
    }

    const program = new Program(
        solanaNFTprogramInterface,
        solanaNFTprogramId,
        provider
    ) as Program<SolanaNft>;

    program.addEventListener("MintedEvent", (event, slot) => {
        eventEmitter.emit("minted", event);
    });

    const umi = createUmi(endpoint)
        .use(walletAdapterIdentity(signer))
        .use(mplTokenMetadata());

    const mint = web3.Keypair.generate();

    const associatedTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
        mint.publicKey,
        signer.publicKey
    );

    let metadataAccount = findMetadataPda(umi, {
        mint: publicKey(mint.publicKey),
    })[0];

    let masterEditionAccount = findMasterEditionPda(umi, {
        mint: publicKey(mint.publicKey),
    })[0];

    debugger;

    const instruction = await program.methods
        .mintNft(metadata.name, metadata.symbol, metadata.uri, mintPrice)
        .accounts({
            metadataAccount,
            mint: mint.publicKey,
            masterEditionAccount,
            associatedTokenAccount,
            signer: signer.publicKey,
            rent: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            recipient: config.recipientPubKey,
            systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            tokenMetadataProgram: MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
        })
        .instruction();

    const tx = new web3.Transaction().add(instruction);

    let blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized"))
        .blockhash;

    tx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;

    tx.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;

    await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(provider.connection, tx, [
        wallet,
        mint,
    ]);

    // console.log(
    //     `mint nft tx: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${transaction}?cluster=devnet`
    // );

    return true;
}



for anyone having the same issue here is fix
  const tx = new web3.Transaction();

    const instruction = await program.methods
      .mintNft(metadata.name, metadata.symbol, metadata.uri, mintPrice)
      .accounts({
        signer: provider.publicKey,
        mint: mint.publicKey,
        associatedTokenAccount,
        metadataAccount,
        masterEditionAccount,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        recipient: recipientPubKey,
        associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        tokenMetadataProgram: MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
        systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        rent: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      })
      .instruction();

    tx.add(instruction);

    tx.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;

    tx.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;

    tx.partialSign(mint);

    await provider.sendAndConfirm(tx, [mint]);
    
    return true;

